# android NumberPicker style as in eclipse

Tags: android, numberpicker

I have two NumberPickers in an xml file which show up in plain in the application. When I change to graphical view in eclipse they show up with a nice border background. How can 
I get this in my app?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's what you meant, but i think this view depends on the Android version, which is installed on the device. I.e. a Android 2.0 device shows the numberpicker in a other style as on a 4.0 device.

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED...

**[SimonVT/android-numberpicker](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker)**

> This is a backport of the Android 4.2 NumberPicker.

So, you can get 4.2 theme for lower API of android version.

Setup is very simple, Please try a sample project in the library pack.